# where is declared layout xml file in module?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout, extensions

i am learning to create a module from here.

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html

And on in this article everything is fine even workin also but i want to know where local.xml file is declared.

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml
>
> ---

When i call this action method how it know that it have to load template from layout/local.xml. why it did not try to load template from other xml file?

```
public function call_blockaction() {
//remove our previous echo
//echo 'Hello Index!';
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`local.xml` is only used as part of your custom theme and should not be used when creating a module. If you have your own layout instructions use something like

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <fooman_example>
                    <file>fooman_example.xml</file>
                </fooman_example>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and then create the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/fooman_example.xml`

Comment: do you mean it works like default layout xml file? what happen if i will delete local.xml? when i create module it was not there?

Comment: Not sure that I understand the last comment, again if you are developing a custom module you should never need to have a local.xml. If you are customising a theme then using a local.xml is the recommended approach see for example http://inchoo.net/magento/using-local-xml-for-overriding-or-updating-xml-structure/